# Laravel eloquent "belongsToMany" with "belongsToMany"

Tags: laravel

I have nested models. I would like to return a pivot relationship in a pivot model. But I managed only up to the first level.

-Resource

```
class Resource extends Model
{
  public function actions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Action::class, 'resource_action', 'resource_id', 'action_id');
  }
}
```

-Action

```
class Action extends Model 
{

}
```

Ex: Its ok

```
Resource::with('actions')->get();

{
 id: 1,
 name: 'test',
 actions: [
   { id: 1, name: 'add' },
   { id: 2, name: 'edit' },
 ]
}
```

My question:

-action

-resource

-access

-access_resource (pivot)

-access_resource_action (pivot)

**Access::with('resources);**  // Returning all actions in Resource. Expected to return all actions in AccessResource

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'access 1',
  resources: [
    { 
      id: 10, 
      name: 'resource 1', 
      actions [ 
        { id: 1, name: 'add' },
        { id: 2, name: 'edit' }, 
      ] 
    }
  ]
}

class Access extends Model 
{
  public function resources() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Resource::class, 'system_access_resource', 'access_id', 'resource_id')
     ->with('actions'); // this calls actions on Resource. Expected to call actions in AccessResource
  }
}

class AccessResource extends Model
{
  public function actions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Action::class, 'system_access_resource_action', 'access_resource_id', 'action_id');
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `Access::with('resources.actions')->get();`?

Comment: this keeps accessing the data in Actions. I need to access Actions in AccessResourceAction (pivot).

Comment: maybe you van chain withpivot

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to access pivot table :

```html
   $resource =  Resource::withPivot('pivot table name')->get();
```

```
and you can access it like that :
```

```html
$resource->pivot->tableName
```

and you can read about that in laravel documation in this link : [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations)

Comment: $this->belongsToMany(Resource::class, 'access_resource', 'access_id', 'resource_id')->withPivot('actions');

Error: Invalid column name 'actions'

Comment: I have to know your models and datatable structure to know your problem but about access to pivot table like I said  above

Comment: I uploaded an image with my schematic.